# Locating a memory leak/source of over-release crach

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, dealloc

Can anyone help me figure out where I should be releasing `exerciseArray`? I get a crash in `dealloc` and when I release just before calling `sortedArray`. This code is called many times.

```
//Set exerciseArray
review.exerciseArray = [[workout assignedExercises] allObjects];
```

---

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    NSString *workoutName =  [event.assignedWorkout valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.title = workoutName ;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index"
                                                                    ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [sortedArray release];
    sortedArray= [exerciseArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSLog(@"*****SORTEDARRAY****** %d",[sortedArray retainCount]);
    for (Exercise *ex in sortedArray){
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",ex.name , ex.repCount, ex.weight);
    } 
    NSLog(@"*********************");
    [sortedArray retain];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

 - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

    [managedObjectContext release];
    [event release];
}
```

Comment: Move `[super dealloc]` so it is the very last thing in your dealloc handler.

Comment: Why does this make a difference?

Comment: The "super" is the container holding your own object, so after doing `[super dealloc]` your own member variables are no longer accessible -- hence the error when you attempt to release them.  Release your own variables first, and finally tell super to release.  See this topic for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523576/does-it-matter-when-super-is-called-in-dealloc

Comment: @Steve: As an aside for the future, please consider converting tabs to spaces before posting here; the auto-formatter doesn't work well with tabs at the beginning of lines, and your code looks funny. Thanks!

Comment: **retainCount** is useless.  Don't call  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: You should move the `[super dealloc]` call to the end of your `dealloc` method. Handle your custom variables first, and then the last thing you do is push the `dealloc` up to the superclass to handle the rest of the cleanup.

---

Now, I'm concerned about the `[sortedArray release]` and `[sortedArray retain]` in there. What you should be doing, to save you the semantics of implementing `retain`/`release` on your `sortedArray` ivar, is declaring a property for `sortedArray` like so:

```
// this goes in your @interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sortedArray;

// this goes in your @implementation
@synthesize sortedArray;
```

Now you can set `sortedArray` easily without worrying about retaining or releasing:

```
// note the use of self, this is required
self.sortedArray = [exerciseArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

You can remove the `release` and `retain` calls now, as this is handled automatically. Make sure to add a line to your `dealloc` method to clean up the variable, too..

```
self.sortedArray = nil;
```

..which will call `release` on your array for you.

**EDIT:** This also applies to exerciseArray, which was your actual question. Wherever there's a Cocoa class involved, you can simplify memory management using `@property (retain)` and `@synthesize`. For `NSInteger` and other primitive types, or when you don't want to hold an owning reference to the object, use `@property (assign)` instead.

Comment: why is self. required? Is it required whenever I call sortedArray?

Comment: You have to use `self` to tell the compiler that you are not referring to the variable `sortedArray` directly, but instead would like to use the method `setSortedArray:` which has been generated for you by `@synthesize`. This is good, because `setSortedArray:` includes all of the `retain` and `release` operations which you would otherwise have to write yourself if you just use `sortedArray = ...`.

Comment: It's not required if you are reading the variable `sortedArray` to, for example, look at the objects in the array. In that case feel free to just use `sortedArray`.

Comment: I just read over Memory Management Programming Guide from Apple, very helpful. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html