# Memory leak, objects in MutableArray are not released?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, retain

Xcode is telling me that there are some problems with the code below in terms of memory leaking.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *naw_rows;

-(void) loadTableRows:(BOOL)shouldReload
{
    [naw_rows removeAllObjects];

  [self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"name"     title:@"Name"          value: self.currentProfile.name]];
  [self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"company"  title:@"Company name"  value: self.currentProfile.company]];
  [self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"address"  title:@"Address"         value: self.currentProfile.address]];
  [self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"zipcode"  title:@"Zipcode"      value: self.currentProfile.zipcode]];
  [self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"city"     title:@"City"        value: self.currentProfile.city]];
}

// here is my cellModel object:
@implementation CellModel

-(id) initialize:(NSString *)newName title:(NSString *)newTitle value:(NSString *)newValue;
{
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        name = newName;
        title = newTitle;
        value = newValue;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *) getName
{
   return name;
}

- (NSString *) getTitle
{
    return title;
}

- (NSString *) getValue
{
    return value;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end;
```

All the addObject lines give the following error:

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line -- Method returns an
>   Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference) Object
>   allocated on line -- is not referenced later in this execution path
>   and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

In other topics about memory leaking i found that this would be the correct way to do this:

```
CellModel *model = [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"name" title:@"Name" value: self.currentProfile.name];
[self.naw_rows addObject: model];
[model release];
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not
>   owned at this point by the caller

So what am i doing wrong? In my first piece of code the retain count should be 1. Owned by the array. And i assume the objects are released when i use [array remodeAllObjects]

Thanks in advance,

Nico

Comment: The ivars aren't being correctly retained/released, either.  Also, getter methods should never start with "get".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This leaks:

```
[self.naw_rows addObject: [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"name"     title:@"Name"          value: self.currentProfile.name]];
```

You own the object returned by alloc-init and you are responsible for relinquish ownership of it by sending it a `release` or `autorelease` message, which you fail to do.

Using a temporary variable, as you propose, does solve the problem:

```
CellModel *model = [[CellModel alloc] initialize:@"name" title:@"Name" value: self.currentProfile.name];
[self.naw_rows addObject: model];
[model release];
```

So, why does the analyzer complain? Because of the name of your initializer. Rename it to something like `initWithName:title:value:` and you'll see the "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" go away.

The convention is that the name of initializer methods should begin with the abbreviation `init`.

Also, the implementation of your class does not assign self to the result of calling super's initializer. This:

```
if (self == [super init])
```

should be:

```
if ((self = [super init]))
```

or, if you prefer:

```
self = [super init];
if (self)
```

---

Also, the memory management of the instance variables of the `CellModel` class is wrong. You should retain or copy the objects passed as arguments to your init method and also release them in dealloc.

The accessor methods also break the [naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC), they should be named simply `name`, `title`, etc. The prefix "get" is only for methods that return objects indirectly.

Comment: I thought that the object was added directly to the array and that the retain count was just 1. But i understand it is created +1 and then added to the array +1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nvz.solutions You are welcome! p.s. It's better if you try to think in terms of ownership rather than in terms of the absolute retain count.

Comment: Also note that all of the instance variable memory management is wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is because the CellModel owns the object. Although you have released it, the object has not. To fix this add code to release the array in the dealloc method.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.naw_rows release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, as a sidenote, you generally shouldn't rely on retainCount because it can easily be misleading.

Comment: `super dealloc` should be at the end.

Comment: Does it actually make a difference?

Comment: Have a look at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523576/does-it-matter-when-super-is-called-in-dealloc).